# display div inside php using echo

Tags: php

I want display my button if it have isset($_GET). I am trying to do like this.

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['project_id'])){
                echo '<div class="add_btn_primary"> <a href="manage_project_users.php?project_id=<?php echo $_GET['project_id'];?>">Project Users</a> </div>';
                }?>
```

its giving me error like

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'project_id' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xamppp\htdocs\mayank\add_project.php on line 101
```

I am not getting idea what I should do for echo project_id in div. Let me know if someone can help me for that.
Thanks

Comment: I typically find that errors looking for `,` or `;` are found before the line flagged in the error call. We would need more of your code to find it, but look at your lines carefully first. If you have a color coded editor, you may find a clue in improperly colored lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats incorrect to use echo inside another echo and how can you start a new php tag without closing the first.
The correct way is to concatenate the variable along the string passed in echo, here is how

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['project_id'])){
            echo '<div class="add_btn_primary"> <a href="manage_project_users.php?project_id='.$_GET['project_id'].'">Project Users</a> </div>';
            }?>
```

instead of breaking the php tags break the ' quotes to concatenate the value in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need again  tag inside echo just use it as below:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['project_id']))
{
  echo ('<div class="add_btn_primary"><a href="manage_project_users.php?project_id='.$_GET["project_id"].'>Project Users</a></div>');
}
?>
```